# Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?

Tags: python, pip

Is there any way to make `pip` play well with multiple versions of Python? For example, I want to use `pip` to explicitly install things to either my site 2.5 installation or my site 2.6 installation.

For example, with `easy_install`, I use `easy_install-2.{5,6}`.

And, yes — I know about virtualenv, and no — it's not a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: @YiboYang does it work with things like `pip34` and `pip35`?

Comment: @JinSnow It should, provided `pip3.x` actually manages the python version that you want to install packages to (perhaps run `pip3.x -V` to see). Or use @Hugo's solution to have better control over lots of python versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919569/install-a-module-using-pip-for-specific-python-version

Answer (score 957, accepted):

The [current recommendation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) is to use `python -m pip`, where `python` is the version of Python you would like to use. This is the recommendation because it works across all versions of Python, and in all forms of virtualenv. For example:

```
# The system default python:
$ python -m pip install fish

# A virtualenv's python:
$ .env/bin/python -m pip install fish

# A specific version of python:
$ python-3.6 -m pip install fish
```

Previous answer, left for posterity:

Since version 0.8, Pip supports `pip-{version}`. You can use it the same as `easy_install-{version}`:

```
$ pip-2.5 install myfoopackage
$ pip-2.6 install otherpackage
$ pip-2.7 install mybarpackage
```

---

**EDIT**: pip changed its schema to use `pipVERSION` instead of `pip-VERSION` in version 1.5. You should use the following if you have `pip >= 1.5`:

```
$ pip2.6 install otherpackage
$ pip2.7 install mybarpackage
```

Check https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1053 for more details

---

References:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/200
- <s>http://www.pip-installer.org/docs/pip/en/0.8.3/news.html#id4</s>
  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v0-8 or
  https://web.archive.org/web/20140310013920/http://www.pip-installer.org:80/docs/pip/en/0.8.3/news.html#id4

Comment: Doesn't work.  Although the latest version of pip installed a pip-2.6 script, it didn't bother to install a pip-2.5 script.

Comment: You need to update your python2.5 pip version... It only creates pip-{PYVERSION} under the python you are using pip.

Comment: This is incorrect. I'm running pip 1.2.1 with Python2.7 on Ubuntu, and there are no alternative pip versions.

Comment: @Cerin, you may have installed only one version of pip, and then you have only `pip` and `pip-2.7`, and that's correct. I have `pip` installed in my system-wide `Python 2.4`, and created right now a fresh `virtualenv` with `pip 1.2.1` and it works perfectly: I have a `pip`, `pip-2.7` and `pip-2.4`. Take a look at my output: https://gist.github.com/3828343

Comment: @rodling: probably you didn't installed `pip` via `pip`/`easy_install` or `get-pip.py` or you don't have python2.7. if you have python2.7, try: `pip install --upgrade pip` and you should have `pip` and `pip-2.7`

Comment: FYI - I tried the steps above and found PIP was now using `pip2.7` instead of `pip-2.7` in CentOS

Comment: @Andres: it is not only in CentOS, it was changed in pip 1.5. This pull request introduced this change: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1053. I am going to update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @HugoTavares how can I change the default version that runs when only executed 'pip'??

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde: the program `pip` gets picked based on the environment variable $PATH. If you want to change what is the "default" pip program, reorder the $PATH environment variable. Search for something like "path environment variable linux" for more details on $PATH.

Comment: This still leaves a problem: `pip` doesn't make versioned scripts executables. So if I install the same package for two versions of `python`, they will overwrite each other's scripts.

Comment: does simple `pip` default to the latest version?

Comment: I got a "`locale.Error: unsupported locale setting`" using this method. Fixed it by using "`export LC_ALL=C`" before the "`python -m pip install ...`" command.

Comment: what exactly does the -m flag stand for / do?

Comment: How does one distinguish between 32 and 64 bit python?

Comment: I leave the dash - out. python3.6 instead of python-3.6.

Comment: If `pip` wasn't installed with python, then `pythonx.y -m pip install fish` will generate the error `/usr/bin/pythonx.y: No module named pip`. This can be resolved by installing `pip`, as per these [instructions for Ubuntu](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/).

Comment: Why these both mixes up every time?

Comment: this doesnt work with python 3 it seems?

Comment: none of these, except specifying the path to the python executable, worked for me.

Answer (score 182):

On Windows, you can execute the pip module using a given Python version through the [Python launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/#installation), `py.exe`, if you chose to install it during Python 3 setup.

```
py -3 -m pip install packagename
py -2 -m pip install packagename
```

You can be even more specific and request an exact sub-version of Python:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install packagename
```

To get a list of all installed Python versions available through the launcher, run:

```
py --list
```

Alternatively, you can launch the desired Python executable directly:

```
C:/path/to/specific/python.exe -m pip install packagename
```

Comment: having both 2.7 and 3.5 installed on windows, this worked right away

Comment: Is there no way to have `python2`, `python3`, `pip2` and `pip3` on Windows?

Comment: this worked for me on windows. had 3 installed and then installed 2

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! Can't believe how difficult it was. (None of these or variations **python-3.7 -m pip install** or **python-3.7 -m pip install** or **python3.7 -m pip install** worked for me...)

Comment: **py -3.6 -m pip install packagename** does not work. I get "Unknown option: -3" Nor do the options jeppoo1 tried.

Comment: How does py know where each version is located? Is it something that I can configure myself?

Comment: none of these, except specifying the path, worked for me.

Answer (score 79):

`/path/to/python2.{5,6} /path/to/pip install PackageName` doesn't work?

For this to work on any python version that doesn't have pip already installed you need to download pip and do `python*version* setup.py install`. For example `python3.3 setup.py install`. This resolves the import error in the comments.  (As suggested by @hbdgaf)

Comment: For this to work on say python 3 you need to download pip and do "python3 setup.py install". Personally I find this solution to be not very nice. For a start I didn't even know the pip command wasn't a binary. This isn't a criticism of @bwinton, I'm just surprised there isn't a better way to do this.

Comment: "ImportError: No module named pkg_resources"

Comment: Same as @Cerin "ImportError: No module named pkg_resources"

Comment: I'm baffled that the problem with the importerror got more upticks than the solution to the same one comment above it.

Comment: Also, /path/to/pip is this: python2.{5,6}/Scripts/pip2.{5,6}

Comment: To call a module of python you should use `python2.7 -m pip install PackageName`

Answer (score 58):

I had python 2.6 installed by default (Amazon EC2 AMI), but needed python2.7 plus some external packages for my application. Assuming you already installed python2.7 alongside with default python (2.6 in my case). Here is how to install pip and packages for non-default python2.7

Install pip for your python version:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python27 get-pip.py
```

Use specific pip version to install packages:

```
pip2.7 install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: great worked for me for python 3.4 with following: `python3 get-pip.py` and later using pip command with `pip34 install example`

Comment: This worked when I used 'python2.7 get-pip.py' instead of 'python27 get-pip.py'

Comment: Man that felt sketchy but it worked for me installing pip2.6 on Centos 5.

Comment: Got `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip` when I tried `python2.6 get-pip.py`

Comment: How to do `python2.7 get-pip.py` without sudo?

Comment: Worked for me on Win 7 64 bits on which I have installed Python 2.7.x 32 bits and 3.5.x 64 bits

Comment: This is not a solution if the host does not have internet connectivity. What does that script do?

Answer (score 31):

It worked for me in windows this way:

1. I changed the name of python files python.py and pythonw.exe to python3.py pythonw3.py
2. Then I just ran this command in the prompt:

   `python3 -m pip install package`

Comment: Just for anyone else figuring out how to install packages in python3 using pip on mac, this command is how you install packages. I spent hours searching and I've finally found it!

Answer (score 29):

Other answers show how to use pip with both 2.X and 3.X Python, but does not show **how to handle the case of multiple Python distributions (eg. original Python and Anaconda Python)**.

I have a total of 3 Python versions: original Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 and Anaconda Python 3.5.

Here is how I install a package into:

1. Original **Python 3.5**:

   ```
   /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install python-daemon
   ```
2. Original **Python 2.7**:

   ```
   /usr/bin/python -m pip install python-daemon
   ```
3. **Anaconda Python 3.5**:

   ```
   python3 -m pip install python-daemon
   ```

   or

   ```
   pip3 install python-daemon
   ```

   Simpler, as Anaconda overrides original Python binaries in user environment.

   *Of course, installing in anaconda should be done with `conda` command, this is just an example.*

---

Also, make sure that pip is installed for that specific python.You might need to manually install pip. This works in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: The advice regarding Anaconda here is not accurate... it doesn't "override" anything.  The fact that it is picking up the Anaconda version as default on your system is simply a side-effect of your specific configuration, how you installed each interpreter, and your environment's path ordering.... those will vary for others.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I agree, it was the default on my installation of Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You sir, are the man.  Of all the totally useless explanations surrounding this issue, this is the only one that has made sense to me.  Time to alias these commands and get on with my life!  THANK YOU.

Comment: This is pretty confusing on ubuntu the python3 pip installs as pip command and python 3.6 as python3.  python2.7 installs as python command and pip for it installs as pip2.

Answer (score 17):

From here: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/

Here is how to install packages for various versions that are installed at the same time **linux, mac, posix**:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
python3.5 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.5
python3.6 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.6
```

On **Windows**, use the py Python launcher in combination with the -m switch:

```
py -2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
py -3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Comment: Also consider checking out:  `pipenv`

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue myself recently and found that I wasn't getting the right pip for Python 3, on my Linux system that also has Python 2.

First you must ensure that you have installed pip for your python version:

For Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

For Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then to install packages for one version of Python or the other, simply use the following for Python 2:

```
pip install <package>
```

or for Python 3:

```
pip3 install <package>
```

Answer (score 13):

pip is also a python package. So the easiest way to install modules to a specific python version would be below

```
 python2.7 /usr/bin/pip install foo
```

or

```
python2.7 -m pip install foo
```

Answer (score 10):

So apparently there are multiple versions of `easy_install` *and* `pip`. It seems to be a big mess. Anyway, this is what I did to install Django for Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.10:

```
$ sudo easy_install-2.7 pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.1
Adding pip 1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip

$ sudo pip-2.7 install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.5.1.tar.gz (8.0Mb): 8.0Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Installing collected packages: django
  Running setup.py install for django
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 644 to 755

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py to 755
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...

$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>>
```

Answer (score 10):

On Linux, Mac OS X and other POSIX systems, use the versioned Python commands in combination with the `-m` switch to run the appropriate copy of `pip`:

```
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage
```

(appropriately versioned pip commands may also be available)

On Windows, use the `py` Python launcher in combination with the `-m` switch:

```
py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

if you get an error for `py -3.4` then try:

```
pip install SomePackage
```

Answer (score 6):

**Installation of multiple versions of Python and respective Packages.**

Python version on the same windows machine : 2.7 , 3.4 and 3.6

**Installation of all 3 versions of Python** :

- Installed the Python 2.7 , 3.4 and 3.6 with the below paths

[image]

**PATH for all 3 versions of Python** :

- Made sure the PATH variable ( in System Variables ) has below paths included - C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python36\;C:\Python36\Scripts\;

**Renaming the executables for versions** :

- Changed the python executable name in C:\Python36 and C:\Python34 to python36 and python34 respectively.

[image]

**Checked for the command prompt with all versions :**

[image]

**Installing the packages separately for each version**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple versions as well as multiple architectures (32 bit, 64 bit) you will need to add a -32 or -64 at the end of your version.

For windows, go to cmd and type py --list and it will produce the versions you have installed. The list will look like the following:

```
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-64 *
 -3.7-32
 -3.6-32
```

The full command as an example will be:

```
py -3.6-32 -m pip install (package)
```

If you want to get more indepth, to install a specific version of a package on a specific version of python, use ==(version) after the package. As an example,

```
py -3.6-32 -m pip install opencv-python==4.1.0.25
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my take on the problem.  Works for Python3.  The main features are:

- Each Python version is compiled from source
- All versions are installed locally
- Does not mangle your system's default Python installation in any way
- Each Python version is isolated with virtualenv

Prerequisites:  If you are using some bare-bones thin client with no extra turf installed, you should run this first (in ubuntu 18.04 at least, extra packages added for convenience):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake

sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev \
openssl libssl-dev libffi-dev unzip pciutils net-tools \
libblas-dev gfortran libblas3
```

The steps are as follows:

0. If you have several extra python versions installed in some other way, get rid of them, e.g., remove *$HOME/.local/lib/python3.x*, etc. (also the globally installed ones).  Don't touch your system's default python3 version though.
1. Download source for different python versions under the following directory structure:

   ```
    $HOME/
        python_versions/ : download Python-*.tgz packages here and "tar xvf" them.  You'll get directories like this:
          Python-3.4.8/
          Python-3.6.5/
          Python-3.x.y/
          ...
   ```
2. At each "Python-3.x.y/" directory, do the following (do **NOT** use "sudo" in any of the steps!):

   ```
    mkdir root
    ./configure --prefix=$PWD/root 
    make -j 2
    make install
    virtualenv --no-site-packages -p root/bin/python3.x env
   ```
3. At "python_versions/" create files like this:

   ```
    env_python3x.bash:

    #!/bin/bash
    echo "type deactivate to exit"
    source $HOME/python_versions/Python-3.x.y/env/bin/activate
   ```
4. Now, anytime you wish to opt for python3.x, do

   ```
    source $HOME/python_versions/env_python3x.bash
   ```

to enter the virtualenv

6. While in the virtualenv, install your favorite python packages with

   ```
    pip install --upgrade package_name
   ```
7. To exit the virtualenv and python version just type "deactivate"

**UPDATE**

It seems that `--no-site-packages` is deprecated.  There's an easy fix for this:  Once you have activated the virtualenv, just point the HOME env variable to somewhere else than your actual home directory, i.e.:

```
export HOME=some/where/else
```

A nice way to do this in general is:

- Create virtualenv
- Activate virtualenv
- If you want to "recycle" existing libraries to your virtualenv, softlink them from your existing install, i.e.
  `ln -s $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy $PWD/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`
- Do `export PYTHONPATH=`, `export HOME=/some/other/dir`

Now you should have custom-isolated virtualenv.

**UPDATE 2 / SUDO**

Wan't to force sudo to use your virtualenv?

```
Defaults        secure_path="/home/USENAME/Python-3.x.y/env/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
Defaults        env_keep += "VIRTUAL_ENV"
Defaults        env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"
```

Now try "sudo python3 --version" and magic should happen

**UPDATE 3 / DOCKER**

Enable virtualenv inside your docker (of course, you have built it in your docker image):

```
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/USER/Python-3.x.y/env
ENV PYTHONPATH=
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can use one of the following commands:**

```
pip2 install SomePackage
pip3 install SomePackage
```

---

```
python2 -m pip install SomePackage  
python3 -m pip install SomePackage
```

---

And of course, make sure that you have the correct version of pip installed

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

---

I haven't used these commands myself but, some answers above suggests using them to specify exactly the version of python you want to use

```
pip-2.7 install SomePackage
python-3.6 -m pip install SomePackage
```

Answer (score 3):

For python 3 and Windows OS, I always use this syntax to install packages on different version:

First I always use Git Bash Command Prompt.

Here an example installing urllib package.

**Default Python version:**(The normal pip command)

```
pip install urllib3
```

**For the other versions**

```
py -3.8 -m pip install urllib3
```

> **py** => for python
>
> **-3.8** => for the version (I'm using the 3.8.7 version) but **if you're using the 3.7.7 version it will be "-3.7"**
>
> **-m** : just because or for modify
>
> **pip install urllib3** : the normal pip command

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers here address the issue but I want to add something what was continually confusing me with regard to creating an alternate installation of python in the `/usr/local` on CentOS 7. When I installed there, it appeared like pip was working since I could use `pip2.7 install` and it would install modules. However, what I couldn't figure out was why my newly installed version of python wasn't seeing what I was installing.

It turns out in CentOS 7 that there is already a python2.7 and a pip2.7 in the `/usr/bin` folder. To install pip for your new python distribution, you need to specifically tell sudo to go to `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m ensurepip
```

This should get pip2.7 installed in your `/usr/local/bin` folder along with your version of python. The trick is that when you want to install modules, you either need to modify the sudo `$PATH` variable to include `/usr/local/bin` or you need to execute

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install <module>
```

if you want to install a new module. It took me forever to remember that `sudo` wasn't immediately seeing `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [pip](/questions/tagged/pip)`22.3`, you can use [*`--python` option to allow `pip` to manage Python environments other than the one pip is installed in.*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id139)

```
python -m pip --python <PATH_TO_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_YOU_WANT_TO_MANAGE> install package_name
```

Quoting [from the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/python-option/):

> Occasionally, you may want to use `pip` to manage a Python
> installation other than the one `pip` is installed into. In this case,
> you can use the `--python` option to specify the interpreter you want
> to manage. This option can take one of two values:
>
> 1. The path to a Python executable.
> 2. The path to a virtual environment.
>
> In both cases, `pip` will run exactly as if it had been invoked from
> that Python environment.
>
> One example of where this might be useful is to manage a virtual
> environment that does not have `pip` installed.
>
> ```
> $ python -m venv .venv --without-pip
> $ python -m pip --python .venv install SomePackage
> [...]
> Successfully installed SomePackage
> ```
>
> You could also use `--python .venv/bin/python` (or on Windows,
> `--python .venv\Scripts\python.exe`) if you wanted to be explicit, but
> the virtual environment name is shorter and works exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Context: Archlinux

Action:
Install python2-pip:
`sudo pacman -S python2-pip`

You now have pip2.7:
`sudo pip2.7 install boto`

Test (in my case I needed 'boto'):
Run the following commands:

```
python2
import boto
```

Success: No error.

Exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

for example, if you set other versions (e.g. 3.5) as default and want to install pip for python 2.7:

1. download pip at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip (tar)
2. unzip tar file
3. cd to the file’s directory
4. sudo python2.7 setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

If you have both `python3.6` and `python3.7` installed and want to use `pip` with `python3.7` by default, here's what you should do:

First make sure you have `pip` installed for `python3.7`

```sh
python3.7 -m pip install -U pip
```

Now `pip3.7` must be available, so we edit `.bashrc`

```sh
nano ~/.bashrc
```

adding the following line to it

```sh
alias pip=pip3.7
```

In order for the changes to take effect type in the shell:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now if you type:

```sh
pip --version
```

you should get:

> pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)

which means, if you use, for example:

```sh
pip install <package>
```

it would install the `<package>` for `python3.7`

Comment: Forget the `pip` scripts, they are unreliable. Just use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip`, it's safer.

Comment: Never had problems with it. So I don't see any reason to forget it yet. 
And I don't think that makes my answer "not useful"

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3.8: No module named pip`

Comment: @EvanZamir you probably haven't installed pip for python3.8.
Please see this question on stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717006/pip-for-python-3-8

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way could be using conda and pip. Some time you probably want to use just one of those, but if you really need to set up a particular version of python I combine both.

1. I create a starting conda enviroment with the python I want. As in here https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html. Alternatively you could set up the whole enviroment just using conda.

   `conda create -n myenv python=3.6.4`
2. Then activate your enviroment with the python you like. This command could change depending on the OS.

   `source activae myenv`
3. Now you have your python active then you could continue using conda but if you need/want to use pip:

   `python -m pip -r requirements.txt`

Here you have a possible way.

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple versions of pip, just type

> pip{version} and run command

Example: for python 3.10

> pip3.10
>
> > pip3.10 list

[pip3.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TcSS.png)

for Python 3.7

> pip3.7
>
> > pip3.7 list

Answer (score 0):

**Updating PIP and installing Packages while using specific location of pip:**

I was getting an intermittent error "Access Denied" when using the simple comand line `pip install <library>` on some lab machines that were using pip from a `c:\users\...` folder instead of the `c:\Program Files\Python` folder for all users.
Thanks to MultiplyByZer0 answer above I was able to implement a solution that specified the path to python and then run pip.

Here is the powershell script I use to force pip update and then install python libraries:

```
$fullPath = "C:\Program Files\Python38"
$thisApp = "python.exe"
$arguments = "-m pip install --upgrade pip"
$appPath = join-path $fullPath $thisApp
Start-Process $appPath $arguments  -Verb RunAs -Wait
$packages = @(  "pylint"
                "pillow"
                "pygame"
                "matplotlib"
                "pandas"
                "godirect")
foreach ($package in $packages)
   {
       Write-Host "Installing python Package" $package -ForegroundColor Yellow
       $arguments = "-m pip install $package"
       Start-Process $appPath $arguments  -Verb RunAs -Wait
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated according to latest Ubuntu-LTS 22.04 and for python 3, however similar instructions can be followed for python 2 with appropriate version changes.

You can consider pyenv python environment manager which lets you configure different versions of python parallely without needing to create a separate virtualenv or requiring separate pip installed.

The installation instructions can be found here and it is pretty easy to configure pyenv. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#readme

This does however require you to install prerequisite libraries which can be installed as follows:

**Redhat based systems**

```
sudo yum install git gcc zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl-devel tk-devel libffi-devel make curl llvm
```

**Ubuntu/Debian based linux systems**

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev 
 libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python3-openssl git
```

After installing prerequisites follow the instructions in the **README.md**
Once installation is finished, to check python versions present in your system run the following in your terminal

```
pyenv versions
```

Note if you have installed python versions before setting up pyenv it may not detect the installed versions and you might have to remove them including dependencies. Take care to not remove important lib files while doing so.

**To install a new version of python**

```
pyenv install <version_number> # like 3.9 for installing python3.9
```

Once installed to set the python version as default run the following.

```
pyenv global <version_number> # to set it globally
pyenv local <version_number> # to set it in the local directory
```

You can switch between installed Python versions at any time using the `pyenv global`, `pyenv local`, or `pyenv shell` commands with the desired version number.

Note that this arrangement is different from a virtual environment as it allows you to manage multiple versions of python at a system-wide level while using other system level libraries and packages. However pyenv does have plugins to enable virtualenv support which can be installed from instructions listed here https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#readme

Pyenv can be removed by simply deleting the pyenv folder and reverting any changes made to `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and/or similar files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to for example C:\Python2.7\Scripts and then run cmd from that path. After that you can run pip2.7 install yourpackage...

That will install package for that version of Python.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably the completely wrong thing to do (I'm a python noob), but I just went in and edited the pip file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 <-- I changed this line.

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Please don't do this. The purpose of how `pip` is set up is so that you can install to any given version of Python by **choosing that version of Python yourself** to run `pip`. Having `pip` rely on system machinery to choose a Python version, defeats that scheme.

Answer (score -2):

For windows specifically:
*\path\to\python.exe -m pip install PackageName* works.

Comment: No luck here with that.

Answer (score -2):

for Blender:

```
/usr/bin $ python3.7 -m pip install irc
```

Answer (score -2):

Some useful information for debugging this is the `pip debug` command. It shows the location of the python interpreter that it is attached to in the 1st line (after the warning).

```
$ pip debug
WARNING: This command is only meant for debugging. Do not use this with automation for parsing and getting these details, since the output and options of this command may change without notice.
pip version: pip 21.2.4 from /data/akshay/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
sys.version: 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 06:56:58)
sys.executable: /data/akshay/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32516966)